Generated DatabaseConfiguration.java is Almost Empty. How Config is Read?
I use Jhipster to generate a simple Spring Boot web app named blog, which works well.
Since I am new to Jhipster and Spring Boot, I want to learn by studying the code. For example, I want to know how it reads database configuration from "application-dev.yml". However, when I open file "DatabaseConfiguration.java"; it is almost empty, as showed in below.
package come.example.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "come.example.myapp.repository" })
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {}

Can anyone enlighten me on this? Where is the code that reads database config?
In fact, my goal is to have two database sources in my Spring app. I have found some discussions that are related to this, which is too advanced for me as a beginner.
I thought studying the code may be a good starting point, but that source code does not tells much.

Well, you see all those Java annotations, @Configuration, @EnableJpaRepositories, @EnableTransactionManagement - they're a part of Spring's "magic" - You can for example look them in he Spring documentation - example https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html - they contain a lot of boilerplate code - Check Spring Framework source code on GitHub for more detailed code

Jhipster creates another layer of "magic", and has made it more difficult for a beginner to apprehend. I am not complaining, just an opinion.
